# ManagedBean Inheritance & Common Name

Tags: jsf, inheritance, session-scope

In one of our applications we have two classes of users,

1. Internal Users (`class InternalUser extends User`)
2. External Users (`class ExternalUser extends User`)

We are using these as session-scoped managed beans (basically to inject the logged-in user's details, which has some common detail in the `class User` and a few specific details in each of the 2 classes stated above).

Can I have the same name for both the managed beans (here "`loggedInUser`")?

Faces is throwing an exception "*Managed bean named 'loggedInUser' has already been registered.  Replacing existing managed bean class...*"

How can we manage this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just not make it a JSF managed bean. Make the bean associated with the login form a request/view scoped one and put the `User` instance in the session scope youself.

E.g.

```
User user = service.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
}
```

It'll be available as `#{user}` in EL scope (and thus also be injectable via `@ManagedProperty` in other beans on exactly that expression). In the `find()` method, you can just return either `InternalUser` or `ExternalUser` accordingly.

Comment: Just for my own knowledge... why would you do this as opposed to just keeping business/persistable objects separate from JSF beans as I had suggested? Just seems bad design to begin with to think Internal/ExternalUser should be a managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a managed bean named `CurrentUser` with an `Internal/ExternalUser` as a member? In my own application, I am not sure I'd inject this required data by making the `User` sub-classes double as business objects and managed beans the way you are attempting to do it.